# javascript anonymous object in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

how to create JavaScript anonymous object in kotlin? i want to create exactly this object to be passed to nodejs app

```
var header = {“content-type”:”text/plain” , “content-length” : 50 ...}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1) with `js` function:

```
val header = js("({'content-type':'text/plain' , 'content-length' : 50 ...})")
```

note: the parentheses are mandatory

2) with `dynamic`:

```
val d: dynamic = object{}
d["content-type"] = "text/plain"
d["content-length"] = 50
```

3) with `js` + `dynamic`:

```
val d = js("({})")
d["content-type"] = "text/plain"
d["content-length"] = 50
```

4) with native declaration:

```
native
class Object {
  nativeGetter
  fun get(prop: String): dynamic = noImpl

  nativeSetter
  fun set(prop: String, value: dynamic) {}
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  var o = Object()
  o["content-type"] = "text/plain"
  o["content-length"] = 50
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply first solution may work but it is not flexible i mean it is hard coded value and i am getting some errors  as well you can check it. 2nd solution creates Kotlin.createObject(.....) on javascript side i can't pass this to node.js this doesn't work

Comment: 2017 calling, trying to do the same as OP. is this answer outdated?

Comment: @gromit190 the answer looks like actual, please let me know if you have any problem with it.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a helper function to initialize an object with a lambda syntax

```
inline fun jsObject(init: dynamic.() -> Unit): dynamic {
    val o = js("{}")
    init(o)
    return o
}
```

Usage:

```
jsObject {
    foo = "bar"
    baz = 1
}
```

Emited javascript code

```
var o = {};
o.foo = 'bar';
o.baz = 1;
```

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me, lifesaver!

Comment: The return Type can "dynamic" to "Json". e.g. inline fun jsObject(init: dynamic.() -> Unit): Json {}  This will more than safe.

Comment: using this in kotlin/wasm, i get dynamic not supported in this context

Answer (score 6):

<s>One more possible solution:</s>

```
object {
        val `content-type` = "text/plain"
        val `content-length` = 50
}
```

It seems that it does not work anymore with escaped variable names.

Comment: is this "possible" or does it work and do the same thing?

Comment: Thanks @JaysonMinard, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my Kotlin/JS + React project I have written an adapter for a library that accepts an anonymous configuration object through the constructor. After searching for a while I found a solution using `kotlin.js.json`

```
val options = json(
    "position" to "top-right",
    "durations" to json(
        "global" to 20000
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Kotlin newbie (though not a newbie developer), I slightly extended answer  from @bashor to something looks neater for keys which are valid Java identifiers, but still allows ones which aren't.  I tested it with Kotlin 1.0.1.

```
@JsName("Object")
open class Object {
}

fun jsobject(init: dynamic.() -> Unit): dynamic {
    return Object().apply(init)
}

header = jsobject {
    validJavaIdentifier = 0.2
    this["content-type"] = "text/plain"
    this["content-length"] = 50
}
```

Comment: `Object()` may be replaced with `js("{}")`

Comment: This is the same and shorter `fun jsObject(init: dynamic.() -> Unit) = js("{}").apply(init)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:
Define the following helper function

```
fun jsObject(vararg pairs: Pair<Any, Any>): dynamic {
    val result = js("({})")
    for ((key, value) in pairs) {
        result[key] = value
    }
    return result
}
```

You can then use it as follows

```
val header = jsObject("content-type" to "text/plain", "content-length" to 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to transform a regular Kotlin object into a JavaScript anonymous object using JavaScript's `Object.assign()`. This allows you to stay in pure Kotlin and in type-safety as long as possible. So:

```
fun Any.toJsObject(): dynamic {
    val thisArg = this                       // Allows use in js() function
    return js("Object.assign({},thisArg)")
}

val anObject = object { val a = "a" }        // Or use a regular class
console.log( anObject.toJsObject().a )       // logs "a"
```

Answer (score -1):

The Kotlin/JS standard library has a [`Json`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-json/) interface, and a [`json`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/json.html) factory function taking in a vararg of `Pair<String, Any?>`.

```kotlin
val header = json(
  "content-type" to "text/plain",
  "content-length" to 50,
)
    
header["x-another-header"] = "foo"
```